# For every x number of files; create new directory and move files -- using Python

Tags: python, directory, move, shutil

I have a directory with a few thousand files.  I'd like to be able to make sub directories inside the larger director and move exactly 150 files (filtered by extension) into each of the newly created directories.  I would love some guidance to get me going.  Here is the trifle I'm starting with:

```
wd = os.chdir(r'foobar')

allgzs=[]

for file in os.listdir(wd):
    if file.endswith('asc.gz'):
       allgzs.append(file)

for gz in allgzs:


# For every 150 .gz files: 
# Create directory -- os.mkdir?
# Move files into directory  -- shutil.move?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with a `grouper` function to yield a long sequence in runs of `n`:

```
import itertools
def grouper(S, n):
    iterator = iter(S)
    while True:
        items = list(itertools.islice(iterator, n))
        if len(items) == 0:
            break
        yield items
```

From there, you can do what you want pretty concisely:

```
import glob, os, shutil
fnames = sorted(glob.glob('*asc.gz'))
for i, fnames in enumerate(grouper(fnames, 150)):
    dirname = 'batch%d' % i
    os.mkdir(dirname)
    for fname in fnames:
        shutil.move(fname, dirname)
```

Comment: You may not need the `sorted`, but both `os.listdir` and `glob.glob` come out in pseudorandom order for me, which strikes me as very unintuitive, so I added it in my example.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see, I'll enumerate what I would do in this situation.

- Get list of files - X
- Loop through all files - X
- Make sure file has only one period - O
- Filter out unwanted extensions - X
- Add wanted extensions to new list - O
- Loop through all files in new list - O
- Add them to a list and use a counter so you know when you have 150 - O
- When you have 150 files, move them all - O
- Back to looping through - O
- Once you loop through all and copy, you're done.

There you have it.  Also, this is in no way the most efficient or best way to do this, it's just how I would.

EDIT: sample code:

```
wantedexts = [".jpg",".png",".randomext"]
wantedfiles = []

for f in files: #the files from the folder
    allowedext = 0
    for exts in wantedexts:
        if f.endswith(exts):
            allowedext = 1
            break
    if allowedext:
        wantedfiles.append(f)

counter = 0
countertwo = 0 #used to tell when you get to the end of the files
copyfiles = []
for f in wantedfiles:
    if counter == 150 or countertwo == len(wantedfiles):
        for fc in copyfiles:
            copy    #too lazy to type in real copy code
        counter = 0
        copyfiles = []
    copyfiles.append(f)
    counter += 1
    countertwo += 1
```

Pretty much wrote the code for you, but whatever.
Countertwo is used to copy the last items (as there will likely be some left over).

Comment: thanks for the workflow outline, that really helps.  Can you elaborate on the counter?

Comment: Well it's really a term I made up, although it is a counter.  Basically it is an integer outside the loop (so it doesn't reset each time you loop).  So for each file that the loop goes through, add 1 to the counter.  The first thing you do in the loop is check if the counter is at 150.  If it is, move the files and then continue with the normal operation of the loop.  I can put up sample code if you like.

Comment: that would be terrific.  I also edited op after reading your workflow

Comment: No problem man, good luck on the project.  Also check out some of the other answers, they have more efficient ways to do certain things.  My way is just the mark of a self taught programmer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're keen on keeping the code you already wrote, here is an intuitive way to finish it up:

```
import os
import shutil

wd = os.chdir(r'foobar')

allgzs=[]

for file in os.listdir(wd):
    if file.endswith('asc.gz'):
       allgzs.append(file)

n = 1
name = "subdir%i" %n
for gz in allgzs:
    if not os.path.exists(name):
        os.mkdir(name)
    shutil.move(gz, name)
    if len(os.listdir(name)) == 150:
        n += 1
        name = "subdir%i" %n
```

Comment: You should probably just go ahead and import `os` and `shutil` in your example now, instead of having a separate reminder (Note: it's "shutil", not "shutils").

Comment: @MuMind Thanks for considering my problem.  I am trying to implement your example and it works the first time through but fails on the second iteration on the line `if len(os.listdir(foo))` with `OSError: [Errno 20] Nota directory: foo`  Any ideas?

Comment: @Karol I think that comment was meant for you, not me.

Comment: @Karol yes, my aplogies to Mu Mind, that question was directed to you.  Any idea why the `name` convention doesn't work past one iteration?

Comment: @KennyC I'm not sure... why does the code you posted say `foo` instead of `name`? Did you use it verbatim or did you change the variable `name` to `foo` in just one place? 

(the edit I just made to my answer is unrelated, but I think it fixes another problem that would arise)

Comment: @KennyC Also, it should be os.mkdir instead of os.makedir -- did you get this code running in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just using a list comprehension to make a list of filenames here. Your list will come from `os.listdir` or `glob.glob('*asc.gz')`

```py
>>> files = ['foo{}.gz'.format(i) for i in range(5000)]
>>> for i, fname in enumerate(files):
...     if i%150 == 0:
...         dirname = "bar{}".format(i//150)
...         os.mkdir(dirname)
...     print fname,"-->", dirname
...     shutil.move(fname, dirname)
... 
foo0.gz --> bar0
foo1.gz --> bar0
foo2.gz --> bar0
foo3.gz --> bar0
foo4.gz --> bar0
foo5.gz --> bar0
...
```

The trick here is to keep count of the files we are processing and divide by `150` to map it onto the directory. `//` just means integer division (same as `/` in Python2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) Module for this

```
for file in glob.glob('*.gz'):
    #Do Stuff
```